# Running one time DML/Update scripts using Prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma

Does Prisma support running one-time DML statements, such as UPDATE, automatically?

For example, let's say we want all emails in a table to be lowercase. We make a change in our API so that all future accounts/emails are lowercase, however we want to update EXISTING emails to be lowercase too.

Running `npx prisma generate` and `npx prisma migrate` executes DDL to keep your schema in-sync. However, I do not see a place to hold database "patch" files. These files generally are run once in order to update existing records in a database.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "automatically"? The use-case you mentioned isn't directly supported but you can use the [`queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) API to write an SQL command that achieves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma doesn't support running one-time DML statements automatically.

You would need to use something like a cron if you want to run some function at specific intervals.

And for one time you could just invoke the function once.

As for your particular use case you could achieve it by using the below function.

```
async function main() {
  const result = await prisma.$executeRaw`UPDATE "User" SET email=lower(email)`;
  console.log(result);
}
```

You could know more about getting Raw Database Access from this [Guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#raw-queries-with-relational-databases)